# Overwrite log file using WinSCP command line arguments

Tags: sftp, winscp

I am using Execute process task in SSIS to execute below command line arguments to download the files to some local drive.

```
/log=G:\USER_DATA\IRM\IRM_SFTP_Logs\IRM_SFTP_Log_Details.txt /command "open sftp://bisftp:*UFVy2u6jnJ]#hU0Zer5AjvDU4@stransfer.xxx.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 xxxxxxxxxxxxx""" "cd /DATA" "get GNRC_IRM_XXXX_EXTRACT*.zip GNRC_IRM_XXXX*.zip  G:\USER_DATA\IRM\IRM_Download\" "exit"
```

This is running perfect and every time it appends logs to the existing file.

```
G:\USER_DATA\IRM\IRM_SFTP_Logs\IRM_SFTP_Log_Details.txt
```

Is there any way to overwrite the existing log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable session log file appending in WinSCP scripting, set [`Logging\LogFileAppend` raw configuration option](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawconfig#logging_logfileappend):

```
/log=... /rawconfig Logging\LogFileAppend=0 ...
```

Comment: Good to see you again!. This was much needed information. Thanks a lot :-)